# Can I use the word 'which' when I am referring the subject in the previous part of the sentence?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Lets see this sentence:

> My mom told me I shouldn't go there, I think I should do *what* my mom told me.

In this case we are using the word *what* because my mom told me only one thing about the topic we are talking about. (This is the same as we do in my native language.)

But should I use *which* when I am referring only one thing from a collection?

> But when I am typing something *which* is not a predefined question then Cortana doesn't even try to answer it

Here I have a lot of possibility to type what I want, but I typed one particular sentence. Is this grammatically right or in English we always refer with the word *what*?

In my language if we would use the word *what* then the sentence would mean that I can type only one not predefined question (because only one exist) and Cortana doesn't want to answer that one for me. With the word *which* it would mean that there are more than one not predefined question, and I typed one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distinction in English is different than in your language.

In Standard English, the sort of English you use in writing, *what* is not used to head "bound" relative clauses: relative clauses which are attached to a preceding noun phrase or clause in order to define it more narrowly.

> <sup>ok</sup>The sentence **which** I typed . . . *but not*
>   <sup>∗</sup> The sentence **what** I typed . . . *this does occur in some dialects, but is not acceptable in Standard English*

But *what* is used in "free" (or "fused") relative clauses: relative clauses which act as noun phrases, naming a subject or object:

> **What** I typed was a sentence, not an entire paragraph.

*Which* is used in this sort of construction only to speak of a selection from a list of alternatives:

> There were three possible sentences; **which** I typed depended on my instructions.

Comment: In your last example I agree, but in the OP example using *which* I would use *that*, because there is no multiple choice.

Comment: @user3169 Either is acceptable; I personally never use *that* as a relative unless euphony demands it.